# count before, after and between points in an ordered list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create an algo that will compute several counts before, after and between certain points in an ordered list. Here my "certain points" are the y values which need to be appended to the x values and ordered. Here is a simpler illustration of what I'm trying to do.

```
x = [2,3,5,6,7,9]
y = [1,4,10]

# appending y to x and ordering gives us: 
full_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]
```

so for y = 1 the metrics would be computed non-programmatically by slicing the full_list as so:

```
num_between_before = len(full_list[0:0])
0
num_between_after = len(full_list[0:4])
2
num_before = len(full_list[0:0])
0
num_after = len(full_list[0:9])
8
```

but of course I'm trying to do this programmatically for any list x which are always numeric and any list y which are also always numeric. Both x and y can be of any size but len(y) < len(x). The full ordered list can have the y values distributed anywhere among the x values.

programmatically the output might look like this:

```
# y_val: (num_between_before, num_between_after, num_before, num_after)
output:
1:  (0, 2, 0, 8)
4:  (2, 4, 3, 5)
10: (4, 0, 8, 0)
```

Obviously I'm having trouble so here in my code so far:

```
x = [1434684599341,1434684606154,1434684607190,1434684613843,1434684677605,
     1434684704358,1434684708727,1434684724495,1434684758413,1434684782632]

y = [1434471725039, 1434684613844, 1434684708728, 1434684782633]

y.sort()

for i in y:
    x.append(i)

x.sort()

idx = []
for j in y:
    idx.append(x.index(j))   

counter = 0

for i, k in zip(idx, y):

    counter += 1
    if i == 0:
        before = len(x[i:i])
        after = len(x[i:conv_index[counter]]) - 1
        print before, after
    elif i == idx[-1]:
        before = len(x[i-counter:idx[counter-1]]) - 1
        after = len(x[i:i])
        print before, after
    else:
        before = len(x[i:idx[counter]])
        after = len(x[i:idx[counter]]) - 1
        print before, after
```

Comment: Define num_between_before, num_between_after, num_before and num_after.

Comment: Please explain thoroughly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've attempted to explain more thoroughly.

Comment: How did you get 8 in full_list in your first example?  When would your desired result be any different than combining two lists into one and then sorting it?  If no difference then that's the method I would use.

Comment: @TrisNefzger ah yes your right my bad its been corrected that would never happen

Comment: For 4 in your example -- wouldn't `num_between_after` be 4 rather than 8? If that is a typo on your part -- I think I see what you want. Otherwise, I'm lost. Also -- can x and y have elements in common? If so -- you need to specify what to do in those cases.

Comment: @JohnColeman your right should have been a 4. x and y will never have elements in common.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you, I think this works:

```
def allCounts(x,y):
    z = x+y
    z.sort()
    d = {}
    for i in y:
        d[i] = z.index(i)
    counts = {}
    for i,j in enumerate(y):
        if i == 0:
            counts[j] = (0,d[y[i+1]]-d[j]-1,d[j],len(z)-d[j]-1)
        elif i < len(y) - 1:
            counts[j] = (d[j]-d[y[i-1]]-1,d[y[i+1]]-d[j]-1,d[j],len(z)-d[j]-1)
        else:
            counts[j] = (d[j]-d[y[i-1]]-1,0,d[j],len(z)-d[j]-1)
    return counts
```

With your test data:

```
>>> x = [2,3,5,6,7,9]
>>> y = [1,4,10]
>>> c = allCounts(x,y)
>>> c
{1: (0, 2, 0, 8), 10: (4, 0, 8, 0), 4: (2, 4, 3, 5)}
```

Comment: I just realized that the num_before and num_after are counting the y values which shouldn't be happening. For instance 10: (4, 0, 6, 0) not 10: (4, 0, 8, 0) since the 8 counts the y values inserted into the new sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `bisect_left`, `bisect_right` to get necessary indices:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bisect import bisect
x = [2,3,5,6,7,9]; x.sort()
y = [1,4,10]; y.sort()

# appending y to x and ordering gives us:
z = sorted(x + y)
x_indices = [0] + [bisect(x, yy) for yy in y] + [len(x)]
z_indices = [1] + [bisect(z, yy) for yy in y] + [len(z)]
for i, yy in enumerate(y):
    print('{}: {}'.format(yy, (x_indices[i+1] - x_indices[i],
                               x_indices[i+2] - x_indices[i+1],
                               z_indices[i+1] - z_indices[0],
                               z_indices[-1] - z_indices[i+1])))
```

#### Output

```
1: (0, 2, 0, 8)
4: (2, 4, 3, 5)
10: (4, 0, 8, 0)
```